# A proxy like RDP behavior?

Tags: windows, proxy, remote-desktop, rdp

We are running some old application from our server that have a restriction (with a dongle) to not permit more then 5 clients.

I've managed a terminal server to allow the others machines to log over a Remote Desktop session to this host so they can gain access, and its working like that for now.

is there any alternatives to this scheme (a proxy obviously) i can consider ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The licensing issues aside, seems like a working scheme already. Consider using seamless application publishing to make it look like a locally installed application for the users - look at Microsoft Remote Desktop Services for Server 2008 or Citrix XenApp...

Answer (score 2):

Can you explain a little more about your situation?  I think you'll find most here, well, *hesitant* to help you subvert license agreements, which is what it sounds like you're trying to do.  If you have the option to purchase more licenses then this is indeed the case.

You should contact the vendor and purchase more licenses.  If that's not an option, because the vendor is gone or the app is out of development / support, then you should really consider  looking into a new app.

Comment: If the vendor is actually gone, you're not subverting licensing, if I understand correctly: there's no one to be licensing *from*.

Comment: Yeah, you're right I would think.  Edited to try to glean some more info, then we can go from there.

Comment: @warren: Copyrights never die, they just get transferred to whoever buys that particular "asset".  If the new owner isn't willing to give you a licence, you don't have carte blanche to do what you like; legally, you're screwed.  (Absent a previous licence agreement to the contrary, of course)